# How to make your own CWM flashable stock ROM from "SP Flash Tool" Flashable Stock ROM ?

Tags: custom-roms

I can't restore my stock ROM of device XOLO A500S IPS by using SP Flash Tool. I need a stock ROM that can be simply flashed by CWM recovery. There is no such ROM available on the internet, as I have searched for it, but couldn't find it. 
Can I make one myself ?
How to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are stock firmware images available for download [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2586904) that can be flashed with the [SP Flash Tool](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Smart-Phone-Flash-Tool-Download-235143.html).

In terms of creating your own ROM (CWM-based or otherwise), that is beyond the scope of this site.